# Google Cloud Functions 2 Terraform fails to deploy (error waiting for creating function, container healthcheck failed)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform

I follow official terraform docs on how to create google_cloudfunctions2_function resource and every time I deploy it it fails with error

```
Error: Error waiting to create function: Error waiting for Creating function: Error code 3, message: Could not create or update Cloud Run service ramowka-357-schedule, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'ramowka-357-schedule-00001-few' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

In Google Cloud Console UI I notice that there is no Eventarc created for this function so the trigger is `HTTP`. When I manually edit the function from the UI and add Eventarc by hand (same pub/sub topic as configured in terraform) it redeploys and works.

This is my tf code:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "default" {
  name     = var.function_name
  location = var.function_location

  build_config {
    runtime     = "python38"
    entry_point = var.function_name
    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = google_storage_bucket.source.name
        object = google_storage_bucket_object.zip.name
      }
    }
  }

  service_config {
    max_instance_count = 1
    available_memory   = "128Mi"
    timeout_seconds    = 120

    environment_variables = {
      USER_EMAIL   = var.user_email
      SCHEDULE_URL = var.schedule_url
      DRY_RUN      = var.dry_run
    }
  }

  event_trigger {
    trigger_region = var.function_location
    event_type     = "google.cloud.pubsub.topic.v1.messagePublished"
    pubsub_topic   = google_pubsub_topic.default.id
    retry_policy   = "RETRY_POLICY_RETRY"
  }

  depends_on = [
    google_pubsub_topic.default
  ]
}
```

This is my function code (I made it super simple to exclude code as possible culprit):

main.py

```
import functions_framework


@functions_framework.cloud_event
def subscribe(event):
    print('test')
```

requirements.txt

```
functions-framework==3.*
```

Anything I am missing on TF side that makes it fail?

Comment: Did you successfully deploy manually your function before using Terraform? From what I see, it's a code issue and not a deployment issue.

Comment: In addition, what's this value:  var.function_name? I think it's the issue root

Comment: I have deployed it just fine. Moreover, after tf code fails I see function in UI (marked as failed deployment) and when I add eventarc trigger manually it will redeploy just fine, so it’s not a code issue (at least not python code). var.function_name equals to subcribe

Comment: the code i try to deploy is taken from official examples  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/functions/v2/pubsub/main.py and it’s the simplest possible code so i am fairly confident the issue is tf deployment

Comment: Is your zip well structured? You can try to deploy directly the zip with the CLI or the UI to validate it.

Comment: yes, I can see it’s properly unpacked into functions source section

Comment: I also did something from scratch completely - used copy paste example from https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions2_function with copy-paste code from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/functions/v2/pubsub and it also doesn't work, it's crazy. Maybe some issue with terraform provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and it was with notation I used in `environment_variables` section. I replaced this:

```
      USER_EMAIL   = var.user_email
      SCHEDULE_URL = var.schedule_url
      DRY_RUN      = var.dry_run
```

to this

```
      APP_USER_EMAIL   = "${var.user_email}"
      APP_SCHEDULE_URL = "${var.schedule_url}"
      APP_DRY_RUN      = "${var.dry_run}"
```

and it worked. At this point I am 100% positive this was caused by `DRY_RUN` entry (after renaming it the issue is gone, I renamed variable one by one to isolate the culprit) and I've filed Issue for this behavior: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/260596909

Comment: The suggested Solution Didn't worked for me, but I had to comment the environment_variables. That is causing the issue. For your problem try playing around with the environment_variables